# Use calculated default value instead of null in Jackson

Tags: scala, jackson, default-value

I'm using Jackson 2.1.3. 
My goal is to use some default value for field, when deserializing bean from JSON. Specifically I'm write on Scala, so I want deserializer to use default value for field, if field is not specified in JSON, but default value specified in constructor of scala class.
I can retrieve default value in runtime for known constructor and index or name of missing parameter, but i can't find a way to make use of this value in bean deserializer.

I know, that this problem was solved in Jerkson, but firstly I can't use it, because it doesn't run on Scala 2.10, and secondly they solved it by using their own deserializer for case classes, instead of Jacksons's BeanDeserializer - so they loose some basic Jackson features.

I tried to use AnnotationIntrospector with defined "findDeserializer" method. I extend DelegatingDeserializer with custom "getNullValue", but there was a problem with a delegatee - I didn't find way to get good deserializer in "findDeserializer" method context, without loosing some type information.

Then I spend a lot of time in reading sources of Jackson, and i didn't find any way to provide default values for fields on bean deserialization, without copy-pasting half of Jackson library with weaken access modifiers on few fields.